# Storing TextArea Data

Tags: apache-flex

Should be an easy one, but it's past my bedtime:

**Problem:**

Want to type in TextArea, and when visiting new view and return, see same text. Also when leaving application and returning, text should still be there.

**Current Failed Attempt:**

```
    [Bindable] public var note:String;
    protected function Notes_changeHandler():void
                {
                    note = Notes.text;
                }
```

mxml:

```
     <s:TextArea id="Notes" text="{note}" change="Notes_changeHandler()"/>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why does this fail?   [Other than the fact that it looks like an infinite loop]

Comment: Just as a test, I put a "next View" button to push to a dummy view, and when I pop that I get back to this view and the TextArea is blank again. Weird, no?

Comment: Flextras, it's not infinite because the change handler only changes on user input, not on text set.  But still, completely useless since it's essentially doing what the component does automatically. SQLiteNoob, when you say next view, are you doing a mobile project? are you using states? tabbed view navigator? etc etc?  I'm going to take a guess that your view is being GC'ed so when you come back, it's being recreated.

Comment: @J_A_X yeah, GC'ed!! THat's the problem - I missed that. Yes, mobile, navapp, no states, sorry for the lack of info. Thanks both!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been on in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is being garbage collected and you need to persist the data through an outside, non-view based class or using something like SharedObject.